# How can I define a method on an already initialized object?

Tags: c#, class, methods

What I mean is, if i defined a class

```
class Square
{
     public Square(int x, int y)
     {
     }
}
```

and i did.

```
Square s = new Square(5,5);
int a = s.Calc.Radios();
```

How can i do the `Calc` part in it.

Like a class in a class.

Comment: Would be better if we see how `square`, `calc` and `radios` defined..

Comment: You mean you want to have your square.Radios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a separate (or nested) class Calc, and make a property calc in class square of that class.  You can initialize the property in the constructor of square through a private set.

```
class Square
{
  public Calc Calc { get; private set;
  ...
  public Square()
  {
     this.Calc = new Calc();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to declare calc in the class square

```
public calculator calc = new calculator();
```

Then you will be able to use s.calc.radios();

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can't add properties to an initialized object.

c# is [stronly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing), so objects cannot be adorned at runtime, as in some weak typed langauges, for instance JavaScript.

---

You can **extend** a declared object, with an **extension** method. eg.

```
public static class SomeStaticClass
{
    public Calc Calc(this Square square)
    {
        return new Clac(...
    }
}
```

You are limited to extension methods only, not properties.

As long as `SomeStaticClass` is available in your references, instances of `Square` will have a `Calc` method that returns a `Calc` object, whatever that is.

---

If `Square` is not `sealed` you could **inherit** from it to make a new type of `Square` that has a `Calc` property, eg.

```
public class SqaureWithCalc : Square
{
    public SquareWithCalc(int x, int y) : base(x, y)
    {
    }

    public Calc Calc { get; set; }
}
```

so you could do,

```
var s = new SquareWithCalc(5, 5);
```

---

or, simplest of all, because you control the code, you could just edit it. Reading between the lines, maybe you want something like,

```
public struct Square
{
    private readonly int x;
    private readonly int y;

    public Square(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return this.x;
        }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get
        {
            return this.y;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Radio> CalculateRadios(Square square)
    {
        // Do stuff,
            //// yield return radio; 
        // in a loop.
    }

    public IEnumerable<Radio> CalculateRadios()
    {
        return CalculateRadios(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply make Calc a property of the Square class.

One other comment though is that I would probably design it along the lines of:

```
square.PerformSomeCalcMethod();
```

Where

```
public void PerformSomeCalcMethod()
{
   // Use internal calc object.
}
```

This would allow you to change the internal workings of this method without changing any client coupled to the Calc property.

Have a look at [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)